# Showing one instance of click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have multiple instances of a control with a `class` of `InviteControlPanel`, and a control with an `id` of `FriendControl` associated with each instance. I want to only show the `InviteControlPanel` associated with the `FriendControl` that I click on. Any help? Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#FriendControl").click(function() {
            $(".InviteControlPanelClass").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here's the HTML with those 2 controls. Note, I'm using a `ListView`, so each row of the `ListView`has an `InviteControlPanel` and `FriendControl`.

```
<asp:ListView  ID="listviewBlog" OnItemDataBound="listviewBlog_ItemDataBound" runat="server">                                      
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="blogPostHeader clearfix">
     <ul class="socialActions">
       <li><a id="FriendControl" href="#">Friend</a></li>
         <asp:Panel ID="InviteControlPanel" class="InviteControlPanelClass"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"> 
           <CMS:Invite ID="InviteControl" FriendMessageId="1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />  
         </asp:Panel> 
        </li>
      </ul> 
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>        
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: You cannot have more than 1 element with a given ID. Element IDs must be unique.

Comment: I'm confused, where do I have more than 1 element with a given ID? Is it because I have multiple instances of the panel with ID=InviteControlPanel?

Comment: also, you have 1 extra closing `</li>` tag (line 9 in asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // On DOM Ready, .hide all matched elements.
    $('.InviteControlPanelClass').hide();

    // On click of this element
    $(".FriendControl").click(function () {
        // Find the parent <li>, get the next control panel and show it.
        $(this).parent().next('.InviteControlPanelClass').show();
    });
});
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFfQh/) (Kind of the same structure [i think :s], I also replaced the ID's with classes).

Also, as said, you can only have 1 ID with InviteControlPanel, consider making it unique and using classes.

**Update**
Use this code with the edited above jQuery.

```
<asp:ListView  ID="listviewBlog" OnItemDataBound="listviewBlog_ItemDataBound" runat="server">                                      
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="blogPostHeader clearfix">
     <ul class="socialActions">
       <li><a class="FriendControl" href="#">Friend</a></li>
         <asp:Panel ID="InviteControlPanel" class="InviteControlPanelClass"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"> 
           <CMS:Invite ID="InviteControl" FriendMessageId="1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />  
         </asp:Panel> 
        </li>
      </ul> 
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>        
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: this code shows InviteControlPanel only for first instance and doesn't work for other instances in listview

Comment: thats because your using ID's. jQuery will find the first element and Stop. Change your code to using classes and it should work.

Comment: I've posted the code above, using classes, try it out, it should work.

Comment: Right now, I have to change code to have InviteControlPanelClass to display hide on page load before I can implement your changes, which look super helpful. Do you know how I can do this with jquery?

Comment: you could just add `$('.InviteControlPanelClass').hide();` inside the Document ready. So when the page loads, it automatically hides ALL invitecontrolpanelclass elements.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID tag. You also shouldn't have a panel inside of a list but outside of a list element. That being said, you can change your code to the following:

HTML:

```
<asp:ListView  ID="listviewBlog" OnItemDataBound="listviewBlog_ItemDataBound" runat="server">                                      
<ItemTemplate>
  <li><a class="FriendControl" href="#">Friend</a>
      <asp:Panel ID="InviteControlPanel" class="InviteControlPanel"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"> 
         <CMS:Invite ID="InviteControl"   FriendMessageId="1"    ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
  </li>
      </asp:Panel> 
</ItemTemplate>        
</asp:ListView>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".FriendControl").click(function () {
       $(this).next(".InviteControlPanel").show();
        });
});
```

Note that you could keep the format of your original code and use `$(this).parent().next` instead of `$(this).next` but that (as I said previously) a `div` within a `ul` or `ol` but outside of a `li` is invalid markup.

Comment: Not quite. The element with class `InviteControlPanel` _still_ isn't a child of the clicked element.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Yes it is in this example, take another look at the HTML.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Actually, you are correct! I read the class structure wrong, hang on :)

Comment: @jre247 `children` doesn't work in this case because you are clicking an anchor tag with in the list item, but I modified the code to use `next` instead which should solve your problem. You could also use `parent().children` if you need to insert other elements between the anchor and the div.

Answer (score -1):

Will doing something like the following work?

```
$("#FriendControl").click(function () {
     $(this).siblings(".InviteControlPanel").show();
});
```

Comment: No, because the desired element is not a descendant element of the clicked one.